# urllib.request.urlretrieve downloading the wrong files from instagram

Tags: selenium, http, url

When trying to web scrape from instagram, the code would pull images from the post url even if it was a video. Im confused on why does it take a random jpg rather than an mp4 which is in the else statement.

```
    time.sleep(5)
    posts = []
links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for link in links:
    post = link.get_attribute('href')
    if '/p/' in post:
      posts.append(post)
      

#get videos and images

download_url = ''
for post in posts:  
    driver.get(post)
    shortcode = driver.current_url.split("/")[-2]
    time.sleep(7)
    if driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[style='object-fit: cover;']") is not None:
        download_url = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[style='object-fit: cover;']").get_attribute('src')
        urllib.request.urlretrieve( download_url, '{}.jpg'.format(shortcode))
    else:
        download_url = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("video[type='video/mp4']").get_attribute('src')
        urllib.request.urlretrieve( download_url, '{}.mp4'.format(shortcode))
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose we can use a "Try-Except" block instead:

```py
try:
    download_url = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[style='object-fit: cover;']").get_attribute('src')
    print(download_url)
    urlretrieve(download_url, '{}.jpg'.format(shortcode))
except:
    download_url = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "video[type='video/mp4']").get_attribute('src')
    print(download_url)
    urlretrieve(download_url, '{}.mp4'.format(shortcode))
```

Comment: wow this solved my problem, thank you so much! if you have the time, can you explain to me why the try and except method works and the if else statement doesn't??

Comment: I think "find_element_by_css_selector" will just raise an error instead of returning None if it doesn't find the element specified, hence the behaviour you observed.